# is it normal for a system clock to be skewed by 500ms after reboot?

Tags: ntp

If I start `$ ntpq -p`
promptly, after a reboot, I can see that the system clock is off by up to 600ms.

It takes a while before it converges to the correct NTP time, therefor mildly irritating in our use-case. (Ceph monitors, which are time-sensitive). A following reboot would again show a skewed clock.

Is this to be expected after a reboot, i.e., is the RTC of a PC that inaccurate?

Things I've done to investigate:

1. Have seen it on multiple, though very similar, servers (HP dl360 gen9). But also an old white label desktop from 2009.
2. Saved a converged NTP time to the RTC, and then copied from the RTC to the system clock. I can only see in the order of 10ms of skew. Perhaps naive, but this basically mimics a reboot as far as the system-time is concerned.
3. Explicitly saved to RTC before rebooting; it still occurs
4. Used kexec-reboot; it still occurs.
5. So far only tested with ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible the RTC only stores seconds, and thus (unless the kernel can tell when it switches from one second to the next) it inherently is off by up to ½ second, i.e, 500ms. The same applies when saving time to the RTC; unless the kernel can control when the 1s tick happens, the save is off by up to 500ms.

The obvious workaround is to make NTP fix it quicker: if you start ntpd with `-g` (or even more forcefully, `-G`), it'll be allowed (or forced) to step the clock on boot. Taken together with `iburst` on your `server`/`pool` lines, that should get you an accurate clock within ten seconds or so.

You can then use, e.g., `ntp-wait` to not start your time-sensitive workloads until NTP is ready.

Comment: I thought so as well, but that's why I tested saving to RTC, and then reading from RTC back to system-clock (See point 2.  in the Question). If your (and also my) theory was correct, we could expect a clock skew with a value taken from a uniformly distributed variable between 0 and 1000ms, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Hmm, I need to do more testing before my "doesn't seem to be the case" can actually be claimed. I'll update here.

Comment: @hbogert Well, if it's actually the clock being fast or slow (and not just an error introduced by the set or read of it), then if your 60-second reboot gains/loses a half a second, you'd expect if left it in grub for a few minutes, it'd gain/lose a few seconds. I doubt that's the case. Regardless of the cause though, the workaround applies.